# How to Create Custom Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am extremely new to HTML, JavaScript, and any other coding-related matters. However, I have been relying on tutorials to get a website up for a school project. I managed to use the jQuery library to get my line graph up (from chart.js), but I would also like to be able to allow for tooltips over my content. (specifically, [this one](http://ytiurin.github.io/html5tooltipsjs/)) I am having trouble to allow for the tooltips to show up, and I'm wondering how I may fix this, as I am unable to find any tutorials. I previously tried using chart.js together with powertip.js as well, which is another jquery plugin.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>get1030 project</title>
    <style>

    @font-face {
        font-family: "brandon";
        src: url('Brandon_reg.otf') format('opentype');
    }

    body {
        font-family: "brandon", helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }

    #container {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 32px;
    }

    header {
        background-color: #336699;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    header h1 {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    header h2 {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        line-height: 2px;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff; 
    }

    nav {
        padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 35px;
        background-color: #818181;
    }

    nav ul {
        margin-top: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 22px 0 22px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }


    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 8px;
        font-variant: small-caps;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: #336699;
    }
    nav ul li:hover ul{
        display: block;

    }

    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        margin-left: -33px;

    }

    nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    #linechart1 {

        position: relative;
        left: 40px;

    }

    #legend ul {
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 12px;
                }


    #legend ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 13px;
    }


    #graphtitle {
        position: relative;
        left: 40px;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #linechart1 {

        position: relative;
        left: 40px;

    }

    #legend ul {
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 12px;
                }


    #legend ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 13px;
    }


    h3 {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    article {
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-right: 40px;     

    }

    </style>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="html5tooltips.1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html5tooltips.animation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html5tooltips.css" />

</head> 

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>stereotypes of women in popular music lyrics</h1>
            <h2>a digital humanities project</h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index">home</a></li><li>
                <a href="overview">overview</a></li><li>
                <a href="f">stereotypes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="stereotype_objectification.html">sex objects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="stereotype_weak.html">emotional/weak</a></li>
                        <li><a href="stereotype_femmefatale.html">femme fatales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="stereotype_toxic.html">toxic</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </li><li>
                <a href="counter.html">against the stereotype</a></li><li>
                <a href="ref.html">references</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h3>methodology:</h3>
        <article>
            The lyrics of the top 40 songs of each year over the past decade (2007-2016) were reviewed to identify several common portrayals of women. The top 40 songs (insert tool tip or popup) was retrieved from <span data-tooltip="Refresh" data-tooltip-stickto="right" data-tooltip-color="bamboo" data-tooltip-animate-function="foldin">refresh</span> (pop up for billboard) year-end charts (charting methods) of the 'Hot 100' songs; except for the year 2016, where the chart for the week of March 26 2016 was used. 
            <br><br>

        </article><br>
        <div id="graphtitle">
            <strong>top 40s over the past 10 years</strong>
        </div><br>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <canvas id="linechart1" width="800" height "1500""></canvas>
        </div>  
        <div id="legend"></div>

    <script>

    $(function () {
        var data = {

        labels: ["2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",
        "2016"],
        datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "women as femme fatales",
                            fillColor: "rgba(255, 229, 229, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "#ffcccc",
                            pointColor: "#ffb3b3",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#994D4D",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "#ffb3b3",
                            data: [3, 6, 5, 3, 8, 1, 1, 6, 4, 2]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "women as emotional and weak",
                            fillColor: "rgba(229, 255, 229, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "#ccffcc",
                            pointColor: "#b3ffb3",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#4D994D",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "#b3ffb3",
                            data: [4, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 8]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "women as men's possessions/sex objects",
                            fillColor: "rgba(255, 247, 229, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "#ffeecc",
                            pointColor: "#ffe6b3",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#99804D",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "#ffe6b3",
                            data: [10, 9, 11, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8, 10, 13]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "women as strong and independent",
                            fillColor: "rgba(229, 247, 255, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "#cceeff",
                            pointColor: "#b3e6ff",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#4D8099",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "#b3e6ff",
                            data: [2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 1]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "women as toxic",
                            fillColor: "rgba(238, 229, 255, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "#ddccff",
                            pointColor: "#ccb3ff",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#664D99",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "#ccb3ff",
                            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
                        }
                    ]
                };

        var option = {
            pointDot : true,
            scaleGridLineWidth : 1,


            };

        var ctx = $("#linechart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, option);

        document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = myLineChart.generateLegend();


    }); 

    html5tooltips({
      animateFunction: "spin",
      color: "bamboo",
      contentText: "Refresh",
      stickTo: "right",
      targetSelector: "#refresh"
    });

    </script>

    <br>
    <article>
        As seen in the graph above, the number of songs that feature the sexual objectification of women is consistently the highest in the top 40s over the past ten years. 
    </article>
</body>
```

According to the README file for html5tooltip.js,

[this is what I am supposed to do, but the tooltip does not show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mzMv.png)

Thank you in advance, and I am really sorry if this is not clear! I have been spending hours on this.

Comment: I recommend you to use http://www.highcharts.com .

Comment: could you please post your html ? i am wondering issue with targetSelector: "#refresh"

Comment: For a "school project"  going with pure css for your tooltips might be easier ..  I can't say I would consider it personally for a production environment, but evidently some do: :http://jsfiddle.net/raving/87865bq7/

Comment: Obvious but worth checking: You are including the tooltip script? Your selector is correct? Are the elements loaded at the time of adding tool-tips?

Comment: I've added the tooltip script in this way:

<script src="html5tooltips.1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html5tooltips.animation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html5tooltips.css" />

I think the selector is right as I merely copied and pasted from the readme, the way the developer used it as well! 

I'm not quite sure what "elements loaded at time of adding tooltips" mean, though!!!!!

Comment: It will be difficult to see whats wrong in your script unless you post your html. where is #result in the html ? @zolidify

Comment: Hi @koolhuman I have just added my full code!

Comment: @Zak Awesome example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Try changing your span tag by giving a **id="refresh"**

```
<span id="refresh" data-tooltip="Refresh" data-tooltip-stickto="right" data-tooltip-color="bamboo" data-tooltip-animate-function="foldin">refresh</span>
```

working fiddle -     https://jsfiddle.net/Lcrgohvg/

Comment: it should work, but could you update the new html after adding the id to the span ?

Comment: @zolidify please refer to the link in my post it is working. I just added the library files such as "html5tooltips.1.4.2.min.js" in the scripts section and all your CSS in CSS section of that link

Comment: Hi, it did work when I plugged the script and css in! May I ask if you know why <script src="html5tooltips.1.4.2.min.js"></script> and the .css file did not work?